# How to say "Some" in Japanese

Tags: translation, nuances, word-requests

I need to communicate that I am allergic to some sunscreens (but not all). 
I know that 'some' is a difficult concept to get across in Japanese, so how would I say it in this specific case?

ie. "(some)日焼け止めにアレルギーがあります。"

Comment: 'Some, but not all'. What percentage are we talkin' about here?

Comment: Hard to say since I tend to stick to ones I've tried but I'd say a relatively small amount, fewer than half definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (いくつかの)日焼け止めにアレルギーがあります。
>
> (一部の)日焼け止めにアレルギーがあります。

Comment: Thank you! Is there a difference in nuance between these? eg. one being for bigger percentages than the other?

Comment: there is no difference
if it has high percentages, you can use "多くの(many)"